# Removing exponents from RMD output

Tags: r, markdown

I am trying to output a large number that is stored in a variable in a RMD file. I would like the number to print something like

Large number: 4123125.2

however when I knit the rmd it always comes out as

Large number: 4.123125210^{6}

I would like to do away with the exponent notation to make it easier to read.

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r}
large.number <- 4.1231252*10^6
```

Large number: `r large.number`.

```{r}
large.number <- 4123125.2
```

Large number: `r large.number`.
````

Comment: I think you can increase your `options()$scipen` value; in my `~/.Rprofile` I have `options(scipen = 3)`, and the above does not print out in scientific notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this syntax:

```
sprintf("%f", large.number)
```

you can then define how many figures you want to be printed:

```
sprintf("%.2f", large.number)
```